# помогите определить тип придаточного, пожалуйста!

Tags: синтаксис

доброе утро,

помогите пожалуйста определить тип придаточного предложения:

Лежа на кровати, одетая, курила, **давая ему время закончить письмо** (...)

(интересует жирным выделенное предложение)

большое спасибо заранее!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> определить тип придаточного предложения:
>
> Лежа на кровати, одетая, курила, **давая ему время закончить письмо**
>   (...)
>
> (интересует жирным выделенное предложение)

В этом предложении придаточного нет.

Предложение простое. **Выделенное жирным** -- деепричастный оборот.

Comment: ... я так и думала, что два действия (курила и давала ему время закончить письмо) протекают одновременно, но не была уверена... 
спасибо Вам большое!!! : )

Comment: Придаточное (скорее всего!) находится в скобках с многоточием  **(...)**:
 
 письмо _какое?_ -- **"которое…"** (придаточное определительное).

Comment: ... так и есть! : ) ... и сейчас вижу, что сделала ошибку в заголовке темы вопроса, т.к. никакое оно не придаточное... спасибо еще раз за объяснение!!!